# Javascript code turned function, does not work

Tags: javascript, onclick, download

I found this JS code on-the-line:

```
var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");

link.click();
```

and when I run it, it generates my_data.csv and downloads it for me, I am looking to change this so when the user clicks a button, the code runs.I tried turning into a function called `Testing()` `function Testing()` and I have my link like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:Testing()">Test</a>
```

but when i put that code in a function it does not work :( what am i doing wrong?

the error in my console says 'Testing is not defined'

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F6CWF/

Comment: Where do you define `Testing`?  Don't just describe it, show the code.  Even better, reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle.

Comment: you don't need to write `javascript:` inside a place which is already being interpreted as _JavaScript_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

HTML:

```
<a id='btn' href='#'>Test</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector( '#btn' ).addEventListener( 'click', function () {
    var encodedUri = encodeURI( csvContent );
    var link = document.createElement( 'a' );
    link.setAttribute( 'href', encodedUri );
    link.setAttribute( 'download', 'my_data.csv' );
    link.click();
});
```

Also, you could create a fiddle to help us out.

Comment: He wanted to run some code when <a> is clicked, not do download the file;

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one solution to that problem:

**1**

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = "javascript:Testing()";
```

**2**

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.onclick = Testing;
```

Use the inline variants if the examples above don't work;

**1 inline**

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = "javascript: here goes the function's body";
```

**2 inline**

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.onclick = function() {
  // here goes the function's body
};
```